# image won't appear on the webpage

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have added a few images on my html but it doesn't show up on the webpage. The directory path for the images are correct and the first image appeared before i added the rest. I thought it was something to do with the height so i added height on the css but still nothing.

Not sure if it helps to figure out without the images but i have pasted my codes below:

```
<section class="pictures">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row1">
                <div id="first" class="img1" style="background-image:url(images/page-1_img1.jpg);">
                </div>
                <div id="second" class="img2" style="background-image:url(images/page-1_img2.jpg);">
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="row2">
                <div id="third" class="img3" style="background-image:url(images/page-1_img3.jpg);">
                </div>
                <div id="fourth" class="img4" style="background-image:url(images/page-1_img4.jpg);">
                </div>
                <div id="fifth" class="img5" style="background-image:url(images/page-1_img5.jpg);">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width:1024px;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the images as background-images, you have to define at least a `height` (preferably also a `width`) for all their containers, i.e. `#first`, `#second` etc.

Otherwise (since they don't have any other content) those elements will have zero height, so the background-images will remain invisible

Addition: Actually, it makes more sense to use `img` tags instead of using the images as background-images, if you are not aiming at any special solution that requires background-images. If you insist on using background-images, you also have to define their size and `no-repeat`.

Comment: by elements, Johannes means your `div`s. and you'll need a width or a no repeat on your background image or else you'll get a row of the same image over and over again

Comment: If there is not a specific reason i'd advise to use the <img src="" /> aswell. Edit: typo

Comment: Thank you. using img tag makes sense rather than using the background-images. since I just want to display the images and not as a background image.